# Why does my $.ajax request always fail?

Tags: jquery

This is how I use `$.ajax`

```
var link = "http://www.myapp.net/..."

$.ajax({
    url: link,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(html){

    },
    error: function(){

    }
});
```

The result of the request is either an empty page or a page with just a number. So error callback actually should never be triggered, as long as the request does not fail.

But I always get the following error

```
alert(jqXHR + "-" + textStatus + "-" + errorThrown);
```

[image]

[Here is some information about the error code in the picture](http://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Component_returned_failure_code:_0x80040111_%28NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE%29)

I run my project on localhost. The link in the ajax code points to another project on the web.

Any ideas?

Comment: you sure error gets executed? I mean, both error and success callbacks do the same thing ... have you tried a simple alert('error executed') inside the error callback?

Comment: how can you say that the error function is always executed ?

Comment: is the url on the same domain as the `$.ajax` script? You could getting bitten by the same origin policy.

Comment: `async: false`? AJAX means **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation. From the error it looks like you are running on your localhost, and requesting a link from outside your domain. This maybe helpful: [JavaScript finally gets cross-domain!](http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error callback is executed if the ajax call can't be completed - i.e. if the url is on a different domain (or if you are running it from a local file), if the request timeouts, or if the server responds with an error code.

I'm guessing it's a domain (same-origin) policy error

Update: If you want to do cross-domain Ajax, check out [James Padolsey's jQuery snippet](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/) for just that (uses Yahoo!s public proxy to make all jQuery Ajax calls cross-domain)

Comment: for now I run my project on my localhost. the url in the ajax code points to another page. what could solve the problem?

Comment: Run your web site from that url.

Comment: @Art you'll have to either build server side "proxy" in localhost (server side code can send request to different domain) then use this, or move the code to the same domain as the other page. Apart of that, only changing the remote page to use `jsonp` can solve the problem.